# Why does python script with execute permission not run on Ubuntu?

Tags: python, ubuntu

I have a script/app/program written in python 3.  I uploaded it to my Ubuntu box and changed the permission to allow execution by all.  I am able to run python myapp.py with no problem but I cannot run myapp.py.  I get an error that it is not a recognized command.  I have at the top

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```

That should be right from all that I've read so far.  I even tried

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
```

in the program referred to as `myapp.py`
Neither of them work. 
I was following an online course and all was going well until we got to that point of running python scripts like regular programs by setting the execute setting.

Comment: can you please run 'which python' from unix shell and 'which python3' and update the question with result..also what error it gives when you run myapp.py

Comment: which python gives /usr/bin/python and which python3 gives /usr/bin/python3

Comment: error is : No such file or directory.  I did ./words.py from within that directory that has the words.py program.  I've tried it with two versions of the shebang line #!/usr/bin/python3 and #!/usr/bin/env python3 which should have worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about, executing it from any directory, you need to do two things.

1. Setting the `path` variable. Lets say I need to execute `Test.py`, which is in Desktop, from any directory

   ```
   export PATH=$PATH:/home/thefourtheye/Desktop/
   ```
2. Giving execute permission to the file

   ```
   chmod 755 /home/thefourtheye/Desktop/Test.py
   ```

Then I can execute it by simply typing `Test.py`.

Comment: I wish I could accept more than one response as more than one of you were helpful in solving the problem.  Anyway, the error, it seems was that I had not put a space between the shebang and the /usr/bin/env python3.  I seem to have read somewhere that one should not put a space in there.  Upon adding that space after the shebang it worked as it should.  What a frustrating error in my code!!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot execute file in unix by name without directory name due to some security considerations, so you have to add `.` as directory (it will look like `./myapp.py`)

Answer (score 0):

did you try:

```
$ sudo chmod a+x myapp.py
```

then run the python code using:

```
$ ./myapp.py
```

Comment: it works on my machine. make sure that you are on the directory of myapp.py to execute ./myapp.py

Answer (score 0):

`.` isn't on your path (and it probably shouldn't be for security reasons), so Ubuntu won't look in the current directory for a `myapp.py` program to run. You need to explicitly specify `./myapp.py` to indicate that you want to run the `myapp.py` file in the current directory.

Comment: I am doing that now and still getting the same errors : No such file or directory.  I actually thought it was due to the required command line argument being missing but when I supplied that it gave the same error.  If I do python3 ./words.py arg1 it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You should either call it as

```
./myapp.py
```

or the current directory should be in the PATH environment variable (either as full directory path name or as '.' which indicates the dynamic current path), check with

```
echo $PATH
```

to add it you can run

```
export PATH=$PATH:.
```

Comment: I tried that, adding the current folder to the path and it still didn't work.  Still getting : No such file or directory.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run it like:

```
user@machine:~$ myapp.py
```

You must put the script in the /usr/bin/ or /bin/ or something similar. In other case you must run like:

```
user@machine:~/appFolder/$ ./myapp.py
```

Comment: The same of other answers

Answer (score 0):

For linux users, may be text format dos/unix problem!

try,

sudo dos2unix name_of_your_script

then shebangs will probably get to work properly! That was what happened to me.

PS:
Ofcourse, also your script has to be executable
(sudo chmod +x name_of_your_script )